# How to work out HP Scanjet 200 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: hp, scanner

I am a newbie in scanner configuration. I try to work out HP Scanjet 200 on Ubuntu 16.04. When give command in simple-scan I got error as:

```
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
```

Any body please advise how it can rectify ..

Waiting your reply

Thanks

Anes

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly new at this too, but I had the same error:

```
[bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Cannot assign requested address
```

It went away when I commented out drivers I didn't need in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`. I think I read somewhere it might be a Canon driver. It might not get sane working, but it might stop the error message.

A snippet of my `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` looks like this:

```
# The next line enables the network backend; comment it out if you don't need
# to use a remote SANE scanner over the network - see sane-net(5) and saned(8)
net                # <== Not Commented Out
#abaton
#agfafocus
#apple
#avision
#artec
#artec_eplus48u
#as6e
#bh
#canon
#canon630u
#canon_dr
##canon_pp
#cardscan
#coolscan
##coolscan2
#coolscan3
##dc25
##dc210
##dc240
#dell1600n_net
#dmc
#epjitsu
##epson
epson2          # <== Not Commented Out
#fujitsu
##gphoto2
#genesys
```